# Cookie not deleting from Chrome 85.0.4183.121(Official Build) (64-bit) in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-chrome, cookies

I have problem deleting cookie from asp.net C# side. Its working fine on localhost but not on google chrome 85.0.4183.121 on production server is not running. I am using .NET 4.5. My functionality working fine on Firefox and other browser.

Cookie.Secure = true;

Above solution is not supported because using .NET 4.5

My code is :

```
        HttpCookie CartProducts = Request.Cookies["Cart"];
        CartProducts.Values["Cart"] = null;
        CartProducts.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);           
        Response.Cookies.Add(CartProducts);
```

Please help if someone is facing the same issue with newer chrome version

Thanks

Comment: Try these examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635349/how-to-delete-cookies-on-an-asp-net-website

Comment: you save your cart on cookies ? How you have setup cookies on `web.config` ?