# How to reset cookie value in a session in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies

I have a simple endpoint that will reset its cookie value whenever it is called from the client. I tried `Clear` and `Remove(string key)` method provided in the `ISession` but none are working. It is still having the same value when I inspect browser ---> Application ----> Cookies.

Am I missing anything or do I need to do anything else to reset the session key value ?

This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    var sessionKey = "MySessionKey";
    var value = GenerateRandomStr();

    HttpContext.Session.Remove(sessionKey); // does not work. Session cookie is not removed ?
    HttpContext.Session.Clear(); // does not work. Session cookie is not removed ?
    HttpContext.Session.SetString(sessionKey, value);  // since a random string is generated everytime this endpoint is called, I would expect it have a different cookie value in the session.           

    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Response.Cookies.Delete`. It's important to note that modifying the session cookie on the server side doesn't automatically update the client's browser. The client will only receive the updated session cookie when a response is returned to the browser. Also, you can examine this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6635426/13548895)

```
// Remove the existing session cookie
Response.Cookies.Delete(sessionKey);

// Set a new session cookie with the generated value
HttpContext.Session.SetString(sessionKey, value);
```