# Cookies and session in asp.net how to delete it after the user clicks sign out button

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

I am creating a cookie and a session

```
if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value,txtUserPass.Value) )
        {
            //string useremail = Convert.ToString(txtUserName.Value);
            Session.Add("useremail", txtUserName.Value);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
            string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;
            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now, 
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "your custom data");
            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
            ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
            if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
            ck.Expires=tkt.Expiration;  
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath; 
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
        }
```

I am using this code to delete the cookie

```
 protected void SignOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");   
        }

   }
```

but still the cookie is there and I am able to see the user.aspx page after i sign out. how to sign out and should I also delete the value in the session if so how to do that

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412300/formsauthentication-signout-does-not-log-the-user-out and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx

Comment: I think here is the solution of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51551957/3649347

Comment: Check this once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51551957/3649347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("useremail");
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a log out it is best to end the current session using `Session.Abandon()`. This will ensure that there is no session information that could be leaked.

Comment: So i dont need to delete the cookie?

Comment: Sorry, still remove the cookie and then call `Session.Abandon()`.