# Logout - How to clear cache , asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an asp.NET 4.0 Web Application with C#. I am currently authentication with the use of sessions, and on logout I am clearing the session. However there is a problem when the user presses back, he is still able to see the cached page. I would like to disable caching, of such pages, or make sure that it is checked for.

What is the best way of doing this? If I set the server to not store cached information, will this effect all the applications or will it just be my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this in `page_load`

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

This is the only true answer although it's important to know that it's only a *request* to the browser to stop caching - it doesn't necessarily have to follow.

This needs to be included on every page you don't want the user to 'back button' onto.

Comment: @m.edmondson; Thanks for editing and adding proper description.

Comment: It won't stop the user pressing back and viewing the page they just viewed either. It's just the way browsers work.

Comment: Is this how you get the "this page has expired" behavior in some browsers when using the back button?

Comment: Authentication cookie or session cookie are not completely cleared after calling FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); Session.Abandon(); See this accepted answer on how to programatically expire these cookies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1306932/463478

Answer (score 0):

You can add following lines in Page_Init of Master page

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
```