# disable AskUser in OpenId Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

I create OpenId Provider by DotNetOpenAuth Library.

I use OpenIdProviderMvc project that found on sample of DotNetOpenAuth and customized it.

Now I have 2 question:

- How can I remove AskUser step?
- How can i signout in provider after response to RP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping the ask user step is as easy as changing the [OpenIdController.ProcessAuthRequest](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/master/samples/OpenIdProviderMvc/Controllers/OpenIdController.cs#L60) method so that instead of redirecting to the AskUser action, it always (effectively) follows the path as if `AutoRespondIfPossible` returned true.

You can effectively sign the user out "after" response to RP by clearing the cookie in the same redirect instruction to the browser.  So before returning from the `ProcessAuthRequest` method, try:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to do the cookie manipulation yourself as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412300/formsauthentication-signout-does-not-log-the-user-out).