# SimpleMembershipProvider doesn't destroy session after WebSecurity.SignOut

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am running ASP.NET MVC 4 with all the default membership code. The code for AccountController's LogOff is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I noticed that this code does not destroy the session, meaning that if I sign in with one account, save something to the session, then logout and sign in with a different account in the same instance of the web browser, I can still see the session of the previous user.

Not sure why this is happening. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Session and Authentification session is not the same thing.

Here you destroyed the authentication for the user, but you did restart the ASP.NET session.

More explanatition here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306932/971693

Try doing this :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    WebSecurity.Logout();

    Session.Abandon();

    // clear authentication cookie
    HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
    cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

    // clear session cookie (not necessary for your current problem but i would recommend you do it anyway)
    HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
    cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);


    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*This is more 'the why' part of the answer.*

Consider a shopping cart such as Amazon that has a `'This is not me'` link next to the username at the top of the screen.

If you add something to your cart, but `WebSecurity.Logout` were to clear your session then you'd lose this session data.

Comment: or in other words - they leave it up to you to decide when to clear or not clear session