# session timeout not working in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout

I have done this in my web.config.

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="3"></sessionState>
  <authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
  </authentication>
```

After session timeout it clears all the data, but it is not redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Session timeout has nothing to do with authentication timeout - an `InProc` session is held in memory whereas the authentication token is a cookie which contains an expiry date/time.

What you would have to do is force the expiration of the authentication ticket in the `Session_Ended` event in the `global.asax` - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306932/82586) on how to do that as it's not just as simple as calling `FormsAuthentication.SignOut`.

Comment: protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.RedirectToRoute("~/Account/LogOff");
        }

Comment: session_end hits but not redirected.Also unable to signout.