# Asp.net web page not prompting for login credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect

I am writing an application using Asp.net web API. I use OpenId for login. Login page(has a button "login") is displayed every time I logout. when the login button is clicked, it logs in using OpenId by providing credentials. when I logout and try login again, the credentials are not asked, but logged in directly.
I want the credentials to be asked every time I login.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your logout logic is broken. Please provice a [mcve].

Comment: What logic you have implemented on logout event??

Comment: Looks like it's cookie based, please clear cookie. If it's Asp.NET FormsAuthentication then 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412300/formsauthentication-signout-does-not-log-the-user-out

Comment: It sounds to me that you are not logging the user out of the external identity provider's system when you log out of your app.  Is the user automatically directed to a login page when they first come to your site?  If you "trust" the external identity provider, why the requirement to see the user prompted for credentials everytime?  Also - what is the external provider in your case?

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser feature to prevent your login credentials potentially being stolen by keyloggers. When you've logged in, it saves your credentials so that you don't have to re-type them again whenever you return at a later date.

I use Chrome, but you can find the same shortcuts to whatever browser you use too. Here are some options:

- Press Ctrl+Shift+N to open Incognito mode and try this again - it should ask for credentials
- Open your browsers settings page and tell it to forget all password / login form data
- Open another browser (like Firefox or Edge) and test this with cookies / cache disabled

Upon logging in again, the browser may ask if you want to "Save" those credentials for that website. Simply select "Never" and it won't ask you again. You will always be prompted for your username / password combination