# Preventing malicious user from accessing a page after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I capture a Get request to an `.aspx` file with the help of `Burp Suit`, When I log out of my application by using `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`, If I repeat the previous authenticated `GET` request it successfully gets the content of page, How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: how to check if request is authenticated?

Comment: You must have the Authentification somewhere.. session? Something must be stored to know when an user is auth and whatis his identity, right ?

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` doest the job of authentication

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412300/formsauthentication-signout-does-not-log-the-user-out , Here I was looking for cookie cleanning. Sorry for the missleading first comment I missed the `FormsAuthentication` part an throught of a classic session auth.