# LogOut Button is not working in asp.net master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i click on logout button it didn't redirect to Login_Form.aspx page

```
protected void Logout_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Remove("LoginUserName");
    Server.Transfer("Login_Form.aspx");
}

<Button ID="_Logout_Button" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-power-off" runat="server"  onClick="Logout_button_Click" />
```

Comment: What type of authentication are you using?  Forms?

Comment: Form authentication

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`
`FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();`

Comment: Sir i want to do it without using asp.net built-in functions.

Comment: Try `Response.Redirect("~/Login_Form.aspx");` instead of Server Transfer

Comment: @NadirAli Take a look at the accepted answer on this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412300/formsauthentication-signout-does-not-log-the-user-out), it appears there may be a bug (or intended behavior) with `Session.Abandon()` and `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` that doesn't clear the authentication cookie from the browser. Basically it looks like the answer is to set the expiration on the cookies to a past date and time.

Comment: Ryan Wilson Sir thanks

Comment: @NadirAli You're welcome. Hope it helps, if so, please let me know.

Comment: @rayn Wilson sir i am unable to solve this issue and i am not want to use asp.net built-in form authentication methods.pleas help me

Comment: In each page i also storing the session of user but when i tries to redirect from one page to another it's also through an error that redirect link in not available. Please help me .

Comment: In `Asp.Net` *having a Session* and *being logged in* are separate things. If you are using `forms authentication` to handle user login, you'll need to use it for handling user logout as well.