Session persist for few minutes after log out ASP.NET
I have an ASP.NET 4.8 MVC application. I am using form authentications. Recently I have discovered that pages are accessible for a period of time 0-5min even after logged out.
This is only happening when using the BurpSuite tool with the help of Repeater. This is happening only for a time period of not more than 5 minutes. From the browser, it is 100% unable to access pages after logout. I am confused about how only the BurpSuite Repeater can access protected pages even after logging out.
I do not use any server caching.
public ActionResult Logout()
{
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
// Abandon the session
Session.Abandon();

// Clear session state
Session.Clear();
Session.RemoveAll();
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}


You don't show your logout code, but adding a Session.Abandon should help. I thought form authentication was only for web forms (and not MVC), but regardless, check your logout code, and see if it has a  Session.Abandon()

Hi @AlbertD.Kallal, I have added my sample code. I have already added Session.Abandon also with Session.Clear(); and Session.RemoveAll(). Still I can access protected pages until the authentication ticket was expires.

Sounds like a similar issue to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412300/formsauthentication-signout-does-not-log-the-user-out. If so, the solution may be to clear cookies during logout.
